# What is the cause of EXC_BAD_ACCESS crashes for classes declared in separate files?

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I have come across this problem several times now, without ever finding  the cause.

When attempting to access a property of `ClassY` in `ClassX` I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. This happens even if I instantiate a clean copy and attempt to access the property immediately:

```
let classY = ClassY()
println(classY.someTextProperty)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

As far as I am aware this error should only be caused by trying to access a deallocated instance, which presumably cannot be the case in the above code.

Where it gets strange, is that if I declare `ClassY` in the same file as `ClassX` then the problem disappears. (`ClassY` does have some private properties, but I am not trying to access these and anyway, making them all public does not solve the problem)

I am not including the source code here since there is more of it than is practical to isolate. I have not been able to reproduce this reliably in a standalone project because I am unable to find any kind of pattern.

Has anyone come across a similar kind of problem, and does anyone have an idea for a solution (obviously I can include the definition in the same file, but that is a workaround rather than a solution)?

I am currently running iOS 8.3 / Swift 1.2 but had this problem already in iOS 8.1.

**UPDATE**
Following lots of trial and error, it seems that the problem comes from `lazy` properties and protocol conformance. Again this is not something I can reproduce in a plain playground (perhaps the declarations need to be in different files).

My `ClassY` conforms to `ProtocolY` which has several properties:

```
protocol ProtocolY {
    var number: Int { get }
    var text: String { get }
}
```

When `ClassY` conforms to `ProtocolY`, if it implements either of the properties as a `lazy` property then accessing a property causes the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. If `ClassY` is not marked as conforming to `ProtocolY` or if none of the properties declared in `ProtocolY` as implemented by `ClassY` are `lazy` properties then no crash occurs.

Obviously this is just narrowing down but still does not give me an explanation. I know of no reason why implementations of protocol properties should not be `lazy`.

**UPDATE** Here is an example of properties on `ClassY`:

```
private(set) lazy var currentPage: Int = {
    let subject: RACReplaySubject = RACReplaySubject(capacity: 1)
    subject.sendNext(self.currentPage)
    return subject
}()

var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        (self.currentPageSignal as? RACSubject)?.sendNext(self.currentPage)
    }
}
```

`currentPage` is set in the `init` method.

If I use instead:

```
private(set) var currentPage: Int = {
    let subject: RACReplaySubject = RACReplaySubject(capacity: 1)
    return subject
}()

var currentPage: Int {
    didSet {
        (self.currentPageSignal as? RACSubject)?.sendNext(self.currentPage)
    }
}
```

(and do a `sendNext` in the `init` method) then everything works fine.
I'm fairly confident that the fact that I'm using ReactiveCocoa is irrelevant - I have also tried lazy properties which are simple Strings, with the same result.

Comment: can you show the implementation of your ClassY?

Comment: Not in any meaningful way unfortunately, unless I spend quite a lot of time pruning, because it contains a fair few irrelevant details with dependencies on external classes. I will give a couple of sample properties above.

Comment: I have the exactly same problem!! Did you find something?

Comment: Sorry @oren, I never solved this. As an interesting plus, I came across (what is presumably) a separate issue where I was having `SEGFAULT`s when adding more than 3 autolayout constraints to an array at a time — the problem seemed to be coming from the fact that the views I was referencing were lazy properties on the view controller — when I grabbed a normal strong reference to each of those views in the method and used that reference instead I no longer had the problem. Perhaps this indicates Swift having problems parsing lazy properties...